# RxJava1 to Rxjava2 Migration Error

Tags: android, retrofit2, rx-java2, retrolambda

Converting RxJava1 code to RXJava2 Giving this error, not sure what i'm doing wrong

**no instance(s) of type variable(s) R  exist so that Single> conforms to ObserableSource**

API Call

```
@GET("/search/users?per_page=2")
Observable<UsersList> searchGithubUsers(@Query("q") String searchTerm);

@GET("/users/{username}")
Observable<User> getUser(@Path("username") String username);
```

RxJAva1:

```
 public Observable<List<User>> searchUsers(final String searchTerm) {
        return Observable.defer(() -> githubUserRestService.searchGithubUsers(searchTerm).concatMap(
                usersList -> Observable.from(usersList.getItems())
                        .concatMap(user -> githubUserRestService.getUser(user.getLogin())).toList()))
                .retryWhen(observable -> observable.flatMap(o -> {
                    if (o instanceof IOException) {
                        return Observable.just(null);
                    }
                    return Observable.error(o);
                }));
    }
```

RXJava2

```
   public Observable<List<User>> searchUsers(final String searchTerm) {
        return Observable.defer(() -> githubUserRestService.searchGithubUsers(searchTerm).concatMap(
                usersList -> Observable.fromIterable(usersList.getItems())
                        .concatMap(user -> githubUserRestService.getUser(user.getLogin())).toList()))
                .retryWhen(observable -> observable.flatMap(o -> {
                    if (o instanceof IOException) {
                        return Observable.just(null);
                    }
                    return Observable.error(o);
                }));
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`toList` returns `Single` in 2.x; you have to apply `toObservable()` after it. Note also that `Observable.just(null)` is forbidden: nulls are generally not allowed with RxJava 2.

```
Observable<List<User>> searchUsers(final String searchTerm) {
    return Observable.defer(() -> 
         githubUserRestService
            .searchGithubUsers(searchTerm)
            .concatMap(usersList -> 
                 Observable.fromIterable(usersList.getItems())
                   .concatMap(user ->
                       githubUserRestService
                       .getUser(user.getLogin()))
                       .toList()
                       .toObservable()
                   )
            )
            .retryWhen(observable -> 
                observable.flatMap(o -> {
                    if (o instanceof IOException) {
                        return Observable.just(0);
                    }
                    return Observable.error(o);
                })
            )
       );
}
```

Comment: toList().toObservable() fixed the issue,but adding Observable.just(0) giving another error, "bad return type in lambda expression: Observable<object> cannot be converted to ObservableSource<? extends Integer>"

Comment: Either change it to `just((Object)0)` or `.<Integer>error(o)`

Comment: Thanks lot for the explanation, if you can back this line with some reference link would be great for anyone landing on this question."Note also that Observable.just(null) is forbidden: nulls are generally not allowed with RxJava 2."

Comment: It is on the [wiki about differences between the two versions](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/What's-different-in-2.0#nulls).

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `RxJava2CallAdapterFactory`:

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl("https://example.com/")
    .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
    .build();
```

Comment: but this compile error coming in Rxjava2 when combining with concatMap Operator